# What users should have access to sudo? (node, php, ftp...)

Tags: linux, security

Before I begin, feel free to suggest a better title for this question.

I've registered on Digitalocean and installed a LEMP stack. This is my first time configuring a server from scratch. Even though I picked the LEMP option, I want to host node apps too.

My main concern is, I'm not sure what users should I create, and which of those should have admin priviliges. Also, I want to rely on SSH keys whenever is possible.

- For file uploading/dowloading, I'm using Filezilla. When I installed the LEMP stack, I was asked if I wanted to generate a password for `root`, or use SSH keys. I chose the later option. Right now, I can `ssh root@domain.com` and use my SSH password. Installed ProFTPd and [enabled SFTP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-proftpd-to-use-sftp-instead-of-ftp). `/etc/proftpd/authorized_keys/root` contains the SSH keys that I use to connect via `ssh` or Filezilla, to the server. Neither `ssh` nor Filezilla ask for `root`'s password.

  Since I'm the only one who is going to access via SFTP, I think I can get away with this method. If I need someone else, I'd create a user for him, associate his SSH keys and give him access to certain folders.

  This isn't causing me troubles, but I figured I should mention it and see if someone believes this is a bad practice.
- I want to be able to execute Node apps. As `root`, I installed node, npm and pm2 to keep my apps alive at any moment. All of those are found in `/usr/local/bin` owned by `root:root`. I created a user called `www` and since I store my apps in `/var/www`, `chown -R www:www /var/www`. **Do I really need to create `www` or could I use `www-data`, which is the one Nginx uses?**

  So far, I don't really need to add `www` to sudoers, until I want to use `pm2 startup` and `npm install`:

  - [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#startup-script) requires `pm2 startup` (which generates the scripts to run PM2 after every system boot) to be used by the user who is going to execute `pm2 start` (which starts the node app and monitors it). This only needs to be done once. It gives you a command that needs to be executed with `sudo`. So `usermod -aG www sudo` and execute said command. All good.
  - `npm install` also requires `sudo`. The thing about this one though is, that **I don't want to be asked a password**. I'm trying to use a Git post-receive hook, so whenever I push to the server I want this to be executed (`/var/repo/nodeapp.git/hooks/post-receive`):

    ```
    #!/bin/sh
    git --work-tree=/var/www/nodeapp --git-dir=/var/repo/nodeapp.git checkout -f && cd /var/www/nodeapp && sudo npm install
    ```

    If I do `git push` from my terminal, I wouldn't have a problem with being asked a password when it tries to `sudo npm install`, but sometimes I use Github for Windows/Mac and there's no way for me to provide that password. Let me note that, I would set up the SSH keys to connect as `www` via terminal or Github app.

  First I thought of setting `www` user as owner for `npm` and `pm2`, because I thought that way I wouldn't be asked to execute the command with `sudo`. I was wrong (hope you're not laughing). Next I thought, since `www` is a sudoer, I could make certain commands available for it to be used with sudo. So I `visudo`'d and I have this in the middle of the file:

  ```
  # User privilege specification
  root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  www     ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/npm
  ```

  **What I'm trying to achieve is "let the user `www` use `sudo npm install` without being asked a password".** Is that the way to go? Is there a way to say "don't let this user use sudo with any other command, even if he provides the correct password". Let's say I do `sudo rm file.txt` as `www` and file.txt is owned by another user: can I disable that? I only want `www` (or any other user I create) to able to use sudo with `npm`.

  So far, doesn't work for me. Also, **is there a way to achieve all of this without adding `www` to sudoers?**
- As far as I understand, I shouldn't let the `root` user connect via `ssh`. Is this a vital thing? Digitalocean doesn't provide any GUI to configure the server, so `ssh`ing as `root` is my only way to configure stuff like the Nginx settings.
- Nginx is executed by `root` so it can listen to port 80, but then it serves the sites as another user (`www-data` I believe). Should I configure something here? I don't know anything about this user: permissions, password, authorized keys.. Should I set `user www;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

  What happens when I set up a site using PHP and a visitor access the site? What user is actually executing things, `www-data` by default?
- Should I have one user for my PHP sites and another one responsible for executing stuff like `node index.js`?
- If I set `AllowUsers someusername anotherusername` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, does that apply only to when trying to access via the `ssh` command or also when I'm trying to push changes using Github for Windows/Mac?
- If I set `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, what password am I supposed to introduce when asked by a command with sudo?

Comment: This is almost like asking for a CIS benchmark for your specific stack.  It's a very ambitious question.  I hope my answer addresses your key concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Only interactive accounts you intend to log into should have sudo or root rights.  The number of scenarios where a service could justifiably have sudo or root privileges is extremely limited: backups, antivirus, host intrusion prevention.

I don't recommend using sudoers to grant service accounts restricted admin rights.  It is very difficult to contain the set of allowable actions.  Sudoers works alright with fairly sensible colleagues who don't want to intentionally harm your system.  A compromised web server is not a competent holder of such privileges and you want to limit the damage that could cause.

The security risk of allowing root npm install is fairly significant.  npm install doesn't require root rights.  That said allowing your web application to self-modify in response to user requests is pretty risky unless done extremely carefully.

If you want to be able to update your web application, use a separate cron job or service that does that and then reconfigures and restarts Apache.  This service could have the rights to run **git** and **npm install** and this should be limited to user-level **npm install** rather than system-level.  It's very likely that sufficient privileges would be filesystem only and could be limited to your app folders such that the updater user can change things while **www-data** can't.

The most vital things to do when hardering nginx are disabling modules you aren't using and making the server_tokens display less detailed version information.  [Way more nginx hardening is possible](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/nginx-server-security-hardening-configuration-1/) depending on the sensitivity of the system or service.

Don't allow root login over SSH.  Login to your instance as your non-root user and use **sudo** to run commands or **sudo su -l** to become root and do so.

Should you have separate users and privileges for separate things?  Ideally yes.  The more component compartmentalization you can practically have that way, the more secure you make your system.  It also makes it easier to add or remove permissions, because each user has a very narrowly defined role in the system with least privilege access.

Comment: Ok so, no adding users to sudoers. `npm install` does require sudo sometimes, the packages I'm using ask it. So `/usr/local/bin/npm` is what you refer to as system-level? What I want to achieve is what services like heroku do: afer a push to the repo, install the dependencies. That doesn't feel to me like something you would do with a cron job, but rather with a post-something hook.

Comment: When you when npm install without sudo it should install modules to your user directory or to the current npm project folder you are in.  You might want to consider using nvm to avoid the root-privileges requirement. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: With regards to the post-commit-hook or Webhook handling.  That's an interesting one.  You could run the update service on a different port, or run it behind nginx and use either a vhost or URL path to distinguish it from the running app.  The updater might run on loopback on port 8080 and nginx would have it as a proxy backend at 127.0.0.1:8080.  That way you get the on-box separation without requiring a super-powered www-data user.

Comment: Who should install nvm, the root user?

Comment: Let's say I have `/home/www/nodeapp` and `/home/www/repo/nodeapp.git`. I create a user just for the git push and stuff like that. Who should own those 2 folders?

Comment: nvm is not a traditional package install.  Each individual user (probably only the upgrader user) that runs npm should install it separately.  The folders should belong to the user that writes to them.  The group on the folders should include www-data if nginx needs to read the folder.